# Arduino I²C master reader from ITG3200 gyroscope

Tags: arduino, gyroscope, i2c, msp430

I'm using the Energia library which converts Arduino libraries into [MSP430](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TI_MSP430) libraries. I connected the gyro into [Launchpad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TI_MSP430#MSP430_Launchpad) and built the circuit with the required pull-up resistors. Here is the example code that came up with Sparkfun gyro:

```
//The Wire library is used for I²C communication
#include <Wire.h>

//This is a list of registers in the ITG-3200. Registers are parameters that
//determine how the sensor will behave, or they can hold data that represent
//the sensors current status.
//To learn more about the registers on the ITG-3200, download and read the datasheet.
char WHO_AM_I = 0x00;
char SMPLRT_DIV= 0x15;
char DLPF_FS = 0x16;
char GYRO_XOUT_H = 0x1D;
char GYRO_XOUT_L = 0x1E;
char GYRO_YOUT_H = 0x1F;
char GYRO_YOUT_L = 0x20;
char GYRO_ZOUT_H = 0x21;
char GYRO_ZOUT_L = 0x22;

//This is a list of settings that can be loaded into the registers.
//DLPF, Full Scale Register Bits
//FS_SEL must be set to 3 for proper operation
//Set DLPF_CFG to 3 for 1kHz Fint and 42 Hz low pass Filter
char DLPF_CFG_0 = 1<<0;
char DLPF_CFG_1 = 1<<1;
char DLPF_CFG_2 = 1<<2;
char DLPF_FS_SEL_0 = 1<<3;
char DLPF_FS_SEL_1 = 1<<4;

//I²C devices each have an address. The address is defined in the datasheet for the
//device. The ITG-3200 breakout board can have different address depending on how
//the jumper on top of the board is configured. By default, the jumper is connected to
//the VDD pin. When the jumper is connected to the VDD pin the I²C address
//is 0x69.
char itgAddress = 0x69;

//In the setup section of the sketch the serial port will be configured, the I²C
//communication will be initialized, and the ITG-3200 will be configured.
void setup()
{
    //Create a serial connection using a 9600 bit/s baud rate.
    Serial.begin(9600);

    //Initialize the I²C communication. This will set the Arduino up as the 'Master'  device.
    Wire.begin();

    //Read the WHO_AM_I register and print the result
    char id=4;
    id = itgRead(itgAddress, 0x00);
    Serial.print("ID: ");
    Serial.println(id, HEX);

    //Configure the gyroscope
    //Set the gyroscope scale for the outputs to +/-2000 degrees per second
    //itgWrite(itgAddress, DLPF_FS, (DLPF_FS_SEL_0|DLPF_FS_SEL_1|DLPF_CFG_0));
    //Set the sample rate to 100 Hz
    //itgWrite(itgAddress, SMPLRT_DIV, 9);
}

//The loop section of the sketch will read the X,Y and Z output rates from the gyroscope and 
//output them in the Serial Terminal
void loop()
{
    //Create variables to hold the output rates.
    //int xRate, yRate, zRate;

    //Read the x,y and z output rates from the gyroscope.
    // xRate = readX();
    // yRate = readY();
    // zRate = readZ();

    //Print the output rates to the terminal, seperated by a TAB character.
    // Serial.print(xRate);
    // Serial.print('\t');
    // Serial.print(yRate);
    // Serial.print('\t');
    // Serial.println(zRate);

    //Wait 10 ms before reading the values again. (Remember, the output rate was set 
    //to 100 Hz and one reading per 10 ms = 100 Hz.)
    char id = 4;
    id = itgRead(itgAddress, 0x00);
    Serial.print("ID: ");
    Serial.println(id, HEX);
    delay(1000);
}

//This function will write a value to a register on the itg-3200.
//
//Parameters:
//  char address: The I²C address of the sensor. For the ITG-3200 breakout the address is 0x69.
//  char registerAddress: The address of the register on the sensor that should be written to.
//  char data: The value to be written to the specified register.
void itgWrite(char address, char registerAddress, char data)
{
    //Initiate a communication sequence with the desired I²C device
    Wire.beginTransmission(address);
    //Tell the I²C address which register we are writing to
    Wire.write(registerAddress);
    //Send the value to write to the specified register
    Wire.write(data);
    //End the communication sequence
    Wire.endTransmission();
}

//This function will read the data from a specified register on the ITG-3200 and return the value.
//Parameters:
//  char address: The I²C address of the sensor. For the ITG-3200 breakout the address is 0x69.
//  char registerAddress: The address of the register on the sensor that should be read
//Return:
//  unsigned char: The value currently residing in the specified register
unsigned char itgRead(char address, char registerAddress)
{
    //This variable will hold the contents read from the I²C device.
    unsigned char data = 5;

    //Send the register address to be read.
    Wire.beginTransmission(address);

    //Send the Register Address
    Wire.write(registerAddress);

    //End the communication sequence.
    Wire.endTransmission();

    //Ask the I²C device for data
    //Wire.beginTransmission(address);
    Wire.requestFrom(address, 1);

    //Wait for a response from the I²C device
    if(!Wire.available()){
        //Save the data sent from the I²C device
        data = Wire.read();
    }

    //End the communication sequence.
    // Wire.endTransmission();

    //Return the data read during the operation
    return data;
}

//This function is used to read the X-Axis rate of the gyroscope. The function
//returns the ADC value from the gyroscope.
//NOTE: This value is NOT in degrees per second.
//Usage: int xRate = readX();
int readX(void)
{
    int data = 0;
    data = itgRead(itgAddress, GYRO_XOUT_H)<<8;
    data |= itgRead(itgAddress, GYRO_XOUT_L);

    return data;
}

//This function is used to read the Y-Axis rate of the gyroscope. The function returns     
//the ADC value from the gyroscope.
//NOTE: This value is NOT in degrees per second.
//Usage: int yRate = readY();
int readY(void)
{
    int data=0;
    data = itgRead(itgAddress, GYRO_YOUT_H)<<8;
    data |= itgRead(itgAddress, GYRO_YOUT_L);

    return data;
}

//This function is used to read the Z-axis rate of the gyroscope. The function returns 
//the ADC value from the gyroscope.
//NOTE: This value is NOT in degrees per second.
//Usage: int zRate = readZ();
int readZ(void)
{
    int data = 0;
    data = itgRead(itgAddress, GYRO_ZOUT_H)<<8;
    data |= itgRead(itgAddress, GYRO_ZOUT_L);

    return data;
}
```

I connected the osciloscope on the SDA and SCL bus to measure if the results were correct. In the first 8 SCL cycles, the SDA bus was what I expected, 7-bit slave address and 1-bit Read. But the SDA which is supposed to be low on the 9th SCL cycle which corresponds to ACK from the gyro seems wrong. The gyro never lowers the SDK to low to ACK the master.

I bought the product recently, so I don't think there is a problem with it. I'm guessing the master never release the SDA bus to check an ACK to begin with. What am I missing here?

Comment: A link to the gyro product page/datasheet would be helpful.

Comment: Here is the link to  the gyro product datasheet http://www.roboweb.net/media/downloadable/rw-sf-9801/PS-ITG-3200-00-01.4.pdf and here is the schematic https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Gyro/ITG-3200-v10.pdf